# Python Openpyxl - Copy values from column A to B with same rows range

Tags: python, django, openpyxl, slugify

I'm iterating through the column A. Inside this column I'm using two functions to unicode values.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.template import defaultfilters
from unidecode import unidecode
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sheet.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

translated = []

for row in sheet.iter_rows('A2:A74'):
   for cell in row:
       if cell.value is not None:
           defaultfilters.slugify(unidecode(cell.value))
           translated.append(defaultfilters.slugify(unidecode(cell.value)))
```

It all works so far, but now I'd like to paste these "converted" values to column B with the same range B2-B74. Has anyone would help me with this code to solve my problem ? I was "googling" but I didn't find solution so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing it in a similar way to way you read them?

Edit, couple of fixes:

Edit2, minor improvements (I had some tautological logic):

ie:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sheet.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

translated = []
for row in sheet.iter_rows('A2:A74'):
    for cell in row:
        translated.append(cell.value)

for row, val in zip(sheet.iter_rows('B2:B74'), translated):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = val

wb.save("sheet.xlsx")
```

So, very similar to how you access the cells, and then you need to save the workbook at the end! Does this work for you? Previously you were opening the workbook in read only mode.

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an index.

Comment: Have a look now. Needed to do a bit of testing, but that should work now.

Comment: After reading and before writing you can manipulate and transform the data however you like. Also, the openpyxl examples are pretty good once you get your head around the structure of excel http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/usage.html#write-a-workbook

Comment: Made a few improvements because some lines of code were redundent. It should still work and is much neater now. You want to append `None`s to translated because that will help you keep the right values on the right row, and as empty cells return `None`, our job is done for us, so we can remove some unnecessary checks. edit: Though I guess you need to handle the `None` when you translate the values. Beware of that.

Comment: It's worth noting that cells have an `offset()` method which would be useful here.